# Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "sakthi*"} -Properties name |select name

Tags: powershell, filter

I want use filter as variable but throws an error 
can someone help on this

```
$myvar="test"
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "$myvar"} -Properties name |select name
```

Comment: Please show a little respect for those who are paying attention to your question. Put a punctuation mark between your sentences. And if you report that there's an error, tell us what the error message says.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$myVar = '*test*'
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $mvVar} -Properties name | Select-Object Name
```

Pretty sure Name is a default property by the way.

Comment: Yes.  Name comes in as a default.

Comment: The `*` got me.

Answer (score -1):

```
    ###Dynamic Approach to Lookup a User###  

    #Get Input to Define Variables
    $NameLast = Read-Host 'User Last Name'
    $NameFirst = Read-Host 'User First Name'
    $NameLookup = "*$NameFirst* *$NameLast*"

    #Get-ADuser Lookup Based on Defined Variables
    Get-ADuser -Filter {name -like $NameLookup} -Properties * | Select-Object name, samaccountname, emailaddress | Sort-Object samaccountname
```

Comment: My organization has the `name` property formatted as *Last, First* ... so check your Active Directory before using this.